# How to get only the max number of pointers touched

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to build my first android game, and I want to get ONLY the max number of fingers touching at a time.

On the screen I show a number between 1-5, and I want the user to touch the screen with this number of fingers.

When I set the `onTouchListener`, and the user place (for example) 3 fingers, I also get the 1 and 2 fingers indication triggered.

Is there any way to get just the maximum number of fingers, or maybe wait for some ms of time before counting the pointers using the `getPointerCount()` method?

I have tried using this method inside and outside of the `ACTION_DOWN`.

I used `if` and `switch` to try and work around it, but couldn't get it to work.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    ConstraintLayout my = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_motion_event);

    my.setOnTouchListener(new ConstraintLayout.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            pointerCount =  motionEvent.getPointerCount();

            if (pointerCount > maxCount)
                maxCount = pointerCount;

            handleTouch(maxCount);

            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    findViewById(R.id.textView1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView2).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView3).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    findViewById(R.id.textView5).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                    int val = (Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString()));
                    if (Integer.valueOf(tv.getText().toString()) == pointerCount) {
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }

                    maxCount = 0;
                    tv.setText(Integer.toString((int)(1+Math.random()*((5-1)+1))));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    private void handleTouch(int pointerCount) {
        switch(pointerCount) {
            case 5:
                findViewById(R.id.textView5).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 4:
                findViewById(R.id.textView4).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 3:
                findViewById(R.id.textView3).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 2:
                findViewById(R.id.textView2).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
            case 1:
                findViewById(R.id.textView1).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I do get the screen to recognize ALL of the pointers values touching (as I said, if I touch 3 fingers, I get 1, 2 and 3) but I only want to get the 3, so the relevant textView will lightup.

Answer (score 0):

Post a runnable with a small delay when a ACTION_DOWN event occurs (that is first touch on screen), When the Runnable executes after the delay,  maximum touch points registered at a time in the interval will be available in`maxCount variable.

Please try the below code

```
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private boolean isRunning = false;
private int pointerCount = 0;
private int maxCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    ConstraintLayout my = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_motion_event);


    my.setOnTouchListener(new ConstraintLayout.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            pointerCount =  motionEvent.getPointerCount();

            if (pointerCount>maxCount)
                maxCount=pointerCount;

              if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 if(!isRunning) setRunnable();
            }else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if (!isRunning){
                    //set to initial state();
                }
            }

            return true;


        }
    });

}



private void setRunnable() {
         isRunning = true;
         runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRunning = false;

             if (pointerCount != 0){
               handleTouch(maxCount);
               pointerCount = 0;
             }
            maxCount = 0;

    }
};

myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);


}

}
```

Also removeCallbacks of the handler in onDestroy, that is - add below line for avoiding callbacks after activity is destroyed

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

To be more elaborate, the problem I felt that you have is

> Is there any way to get just the maximum number of fingers, or maybe wait for some ms of time before counting the pointers using the getPointerCount() method?

That is where Runnables and Handlers come into play.
If you want to delay execution of a piece of Code for an interval without blocking (Pausing the execution of the thread), Handler.postDelayed() method is used with a delay and Runnable as parameters.Here Runnable can be used to send the delayed task.

I suggest you to take a look into threading in android to get deeper knowledge,
https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/handler-in-android-d138c1f4980e
https://en.proft.me/2017/04/15/understanding-handler-android/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

There are some problems but I will try to tweak it a little.
More important - I would like to learn from what you did and not just copy it, so could you please explain what is runnable?  and what is this postDelay for a handler?

Why didn't my idea worked and what should I think about next time.

Thank you very much for the time you spent about my question.

Comment: Just added some points to the answer, if you are new to programming you should start learning about Handler, looper, message queue, runnable, .. which are parts of threading in android

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will go over what you added and try to understand.
One more thing - for some reason, once in a while I get a wrong number. for example: if I touch with 1 finger a few times and then with 4 - the first time it will still register as 1, and only the second time it will show 4. ( I updated the code to 5ms if that's important).

Thank you again for all the explanations  and I will start to go over what you suggested.

Comment: I'm still having problems with the multi-touch.
When it's just 1 finger all is good, but once I try to get the correct number of the multi-finger touch - things are wrong most of the times.
I do get feedback that I touched with more fingers, but for some reason the input does not pass the correct way.

would appreciate any help.
thank you.

Comment: Try increasing delay from 5 ms, make it 100 ms atleast